# Custom link missing as option in my 'add menu items'

Tags: menus

[image]

Have taken over as admin on a site and there doesn;t seem to be the option in the menu option for adding a custom link. Not sure why anyone would have wanted to hide it, but if they have where would i look?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the "missing" option in the top right, look for screen options

[image]